# ember-addon - afterInstall hook does not update my ember app package.json

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

Im trying to **create an Ember Addon that uses the blueprint** `afterInstall` **hook**.

I have read https://cli.emberjs.com/release/writing-addons/addon-blueprints/

My addon is called `hello-world`.

I generated **my addon blueprint by** `ember generate blueprint hello-world`.

I have now a `blueprint/hello-world/index.js` file.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  description: 'This is my blueprint',
  afterInstall(options) {
    console.log('hello');

    return this.addPackagesToProject([
      { name: 'lodash' }
    ]);
  }
};
```

How could I test the the `afterInstall` hook is called?

**My Ember Addon is in development** (and has not been published), I have **tried using** `npm link` **in my Ember Addon directory and** `npm link hello-world` **in my Ember app. This creates a symlink in my Ember App node_modules to point to my hello-world Ember Addon but it does not trigger the** `afterInstall` **hook.**

My Ember App package.json does not get an entry for `lodash` in dependencies or devDependencies.

Part of my Ember App package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "hello-world": "*"
    ...
  }
```

Running `npm install --offline` does not seem to trigger the blueprint hook.

Answer (score 1):

Ember addons are typically installed with the command `ember install addon_name`. This function essentially is the composite of:

```
npm install addon_name
ember generate addon_name
```

So after you `npm link` your addon, go into the consuming project and generate your addon's default blueprint with `ember generate addon_name`